# HTML grid positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a grid positioning in HTML using CSS. I want to use this for a variety of objects like images, phrases and links.

[image: A grid method (drew up in paint.net]

This is a visual representation on what I would sort of like. The colours resembling the different objects, so it all fits together with no spacing between the 'divs' and 'auto-magically' fit them depending on a set size.

I really want to stay away from any APIs, libraries and I would prefer it be mostly CSS, JS, jQuery and HTML based.

http://jsfiddle.net/AeroMcDoom/quC8V/1/

This is what I have, but I am new to the positioning aspects of html and have been pondering for about a week on how to do this.

```
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
```

('.a' is the 1x1 grid and '.b' is the 2x2)

Comment: You could use [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) instead of *reinventing the wheel*.

Comment: @HashemQolami '**I really want to stay away from any APIs, libraries**...'

Comment: Is table acceptable? If yes then it is pretty straightforward. If no, then it is a bit trickier with divs

Comment: Well, I've tried it with tables, but it didn't fill in any spaces and would keep to the rows specified.

Comment: @KeirDavis Then you should handle the position of each block via JavaScript and try to make something like **masonry** *(jQuery plugin)*. Your choice.

Comment: Okay, if the problem of tables is that they'll keep the rows and columns togehter I don't really get your question anymore: Do you want the boxes to stay together in every case (i.e. also with smaller or larger screen resolutions etc.)? (That's what tables would do.) Or do you want them to automatically break somehow if there is not enough space to display them on one page? (Then you'd have to specify how such breaks should look like.)

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid is a thing that exists. It's a pure html/css solution that has been implemented over the past few years into everything but filthy IE.

Here is a framework generator but use this after reading: http://www.blended-html.com/

css grid is awesome and it provides a non-hacking solution to putting divs and other items anywhere you want, in any order you want, and exactly where you want them. It's better than auto-magic.
Here is a tutorial from one of the proponents of css-grid, rachel andrew. https://gridbyexample.com/video/series-auto-placement-span/
I think that video in particular may be of great use to you, but all of them would be awesome.

Here is an example of grid in action. Feel free to change the names in the quotes after "grid-template-areas" with other names to see how they reposition. https://codepen.io/quibble/pen/NaKdMo

```
#wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:10px;
  grid-template-columns:50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 3px 27px 13px 17px 40px; /*the pixels add up to the corresponding bottoms of each grid container. There are a few ways to do this but I like this one.*/
  grid-template-areas:
    /*This allows you to specify which grid blocks go where. Notice that some are repeated, this just means they span two or more grid areas. For example, box 3 is 33 px so must span one column and two rows (the 30 and 3px one)*/
    "one two three"
    "one five three"
    "one five six"
    "four five six"
    "four five ."
    "four . .";/* the . is for a blank gridspace */
}
#wrapper>div{
  background-color:gray;
}
.d_1{
  grid-area:one;
}
.d_2{
  grid-area:two;
}
.d_3{
  grid-area:three;
}
.d_4{
  grid-area:four;
}
.d_5{
  grid-area:five;
}
.d_6{
  grid-area:six;
}
```